# Is it possible to namespace methods added to existing classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing some code in which I'd like to add some methods to a predefined class, like so:

```
class Model  # this class already exists

  def my_method
    # code here
  end

end
```

Is there any way to namespace this, using Modules or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a mechanism to do this in Ruby 2.0, although it is not exactly clear what exactly that mechanism is going to be. For the past almost 10 years, the frontrunner seemed to be *Selector Namespaces*, but recently *Classboxes* and even more recently, *Refinements* have taken the lead. In fact, if I am not mistaken, Refinements are actually currently implemented in the YARV trunk.

With all currently existing versions (including the soon to be released 1.9.3), however, there is no way to do this.

That's one of the reasons why monkey patching should generally be avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot, simply knowing it isn't yet possible is very helpful in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your methods inside a `Module` and include it in `Model`:

```
module SomeModule
  def my_method
  end
end

class Model
  include SomeModule
end
```

Comment: From an namespace perspective, isn't this the same thing? Either way, the method would be called using Model.my_method, no?

Comment: The same thing as what? And no, not Model.my_method. The `my_method` is a public instance method. In order to call it, you have to create a `Model` object first.

Comment: @prostosuper: My (admittedly not very sophisticated) understanding of namespaces is that they're intended to keep method names, variable names, et al unique. So, I guess I don't see how this solution accomplishes that. If, either way, you're calling .my_method on an instance of the Model class, I don't see what's been accomplished from a namespace perspective.

Comment: @jkjenner: Do you worry of namespace collisions between methods in module and methods in class? Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm worried about. The Model class, in this case, is part of an API which many people write code for. So, I don't want to create method names which might conflict with those created by other people.